# Best way to parse a huge JSON file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I'm having a hard time parsing a huge json file.

The file is >1GB, and I've tried using the two gems: ruby-stream and yajl, and they both don't work.

Here's an example of what happens.

```
fileStr = File.read("hugeJSONfile.json")
```

^ This part is OK.

But when I try to load the fileStr into a JSON hash (via ruby-stream or yajl), my computer freezes.

Any other ideas on how to do this more efficiently? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into the [`json-stream`](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream) or [`yajl`](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby):

Key quote from the docs:

json-stream:

> the document itself is never fully read into memory.

yajl:

> The main benefit of this library is in its memory usage. Since it's able to parse the stream in chunks, its memory requirements are very, very low.

You register events you are looking for, and it returns keys/values while reading through the JSON instead of loading it all into a ruby data structure (and consequently into memory).

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my entire post, but both those gems froze my computer.

Comment: My hunch is that my JSON file is too complicated for those gems. For example, if I have something like
[ {...[...{...}]}] where each "..." is super long, then the gems may stream until it tries to balance out the bracket combos, which might take awhile.

Please note that I did NOT look into how these gems optimize the streaming process, and this is all a hunch.

Comment: Were you watching your memory usage while those parsers were running? I'm curious how long was the program running before you decided it was frozen?

Comment: It was tough to because other apps on my comp started lagging too heavily... You know, it might just be because I'm running on a deteriorating mac from 2010 - although my friend who ran the same script with newer laptop experienced a similar issue.

I let the program go for >40 minutes on several occasions before I decided to restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to parse it.

Honestly, this is not the most elegant solution, but given desperate times, one quick way to parse a huge JSON file is to examine the file manually, notice a pattern, and pluck out what you need.

In my case, here's what I did in pseudo code

```
fileStr = File.read("hugeJSONfile.json")
arr = fileStr.split("[some pattern]")
arr.each do |str|
    extract desired value from str
end
```

Again, not the most elegant solution, but it's low maintenance, and depending on the given circumstances, just adapt to what your crappy laptop can muster.

Comment: If you don't want to implement a custom parser this is a nice but fragile approach. Could you share the regexp you are using? I'm trying to parse an array of hashes with the following regexp code: `json[1..-1].split(/,(?={)/)` But the hashes can have an array of hashes inside, so the regexp is not working properly. Any suggestion on how to make this regexp more robust?